# Tensorflow tf.hessians prints only diagonal

Tags: python, tensorflow

Defining a series of variables

```
a_v = tf.Variable([20.2], tf.float32)
a_s = tf.Variable([18.0], tf.float32)
...
```

And training the model with a given loss function "loss", then calculating its Hessian for the variables above,

```
hess = tf.hessians( loss ,  [a_v,...] )
```

The evauation of that given Hessian

```
sess.run( hess, feed_dict= ... )
```

Comes out with only the diagonal part of the Hessian instead of the whole Hessian matrix.

In theory from the [tensorflow manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/hessians)  the function should support "supports evaluating the Hessian with respect to (a list of) one- dimensional tensors".

Comment: I think this function computes the Hessian w.r.t **each** `x` in `xs`. If you want to get the matrix, use twice `tf.gradient()`, although it will consume a lot memory.

Comment: I did a function with tf.gradient() but is extremely inefficient. It seems strange to me that there is no intrinsic function in tensorflow, considering the importance of Hessian in statistic.

How do you compute for error in tf.Variable estimation and the stiffness of the loss function?